# Datadog: Configure APM for Datadog-Operator Helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, datadog

I don't understand where should I configure my Datadog agent in the values.yml of the Helm chart of the datadog operator (https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/datadog-operator)

I just want to enable APM.

Just to make sure: is the operator is a "bundle" of datadog-agent and datadog-cluster?

Thanks